# How to align subfigures in the two column paper using minpage?

Tags: minipage

I'm usin minipage to plot subfigures. I used figuresize (8 by 6) in matplotlib for all subfigures, But when I compile then in Latex their boudries don't appear at the same position (e.g top right and bottom right figure's boundry should start from same place). I'm not sure if it is due to spacing or anything else. I tried to use centering for all subfigures but it didn't work.How can I fix this issue?

```
`\begin{figure*}[!htb]
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig14.png}
    \end{minipage}%

    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig2.png}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig3.png}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig4.png}
    \end{minipage}`
```

Comment: Look for subfloat or subfigures here.

Comment: Can we not align them using minpage?

Comment: @jerry: The desired alignment can most likely be achieved using minipages. However, adding captions to the individual figure can be easily achieved with either the `subcaption` or the `subfig` package.

Comment: I jus want to add (a) (b) at the top left corners of each figure. Although I tried to use sidesubfloat and I achieved the desired result but is there anyway to get same result while using minipage?

Comment: You could also do them as separate [p] floats, assuming twocolumn.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the whole machinery of `subcaption` (quite likely for a short paper), you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\msf}[1]{\makebox[2em][l]{(#1)}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}

\msf{a}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em,valign=t]{example-image}\hfill
\msf{b}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em,valign=t]{example-image}

\medskip

\msf{c}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em,valign=t]{example-image}\hfill
\msf{d}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em,valign=t]{example-image}

\medskip

\msf{e}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em,valign=t]{example-image}\hfill
\msf{f}
\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\columnwidth-2em,valign=t]{example-image}

\caption{Six figures}\label{test}

\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]